# Add/subtract dataframes with different column labels

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add/subtract two dataframes with different column labels. Is it possible to do this without renaming the columns to align them? I would like to keep the original labels.

Comment: You can simply subtract two data frame columns with the same dimension by running `df1.col1 - df2.col2`. What exactly does not work for you?

Comment: Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: It doesn't work if I am operating on all the columns rather than a specific column. The answer solves my problem. I'll be sure to provide an example next time!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Consider dataframes `A` and `B`

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], ['a', 'b'], ['A', 'B'])
B = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], ['c', 'd'], ['C', 'D'])
```

---

```
A
```

[image]

```
B
```

[image]

Add them together and we have a mess.

```
A + B
```

[image]

Add their underlying arrays

```
A.values + B.values

array([[2, 4],
       [6, 8]])
```

That's closer to what we want.

To get what you asked for, you need to decide which dataframe has the columns and index you want and add the values of the other to the dataframe you chose.  Let's say I choose to keep `A`'s indices.

```
A + B.values
```

[image]

That ought to do it!

Comment: This answer has one down vote. I'd sincerely appreciate any feedback. I strive to provide thoughtful answers and if I can learn what motivated this down vote I can learn and improve this and future answers. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @piRSquared answer which leverage matrices operations (numpy) but ideally we would want to stay in a pandas framework. What about:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    df_A.values - df_B.values,
    columns=df_A.columns 
)
```

The explanation about why we take values is given in @piRSquared answer. Here, I additionally recreate another dataframe to hold the data with the column naming from `df_A`. It seems to me that this was the most important metainformation, but one could also transfer the indices (row names)... Finally, it is also possible to change the name of the columns, try:

```
[name_A + '-' + name_B for name_A, name_B in zip(list(df_A.columns),list(df_B.columns))]
```

Hope it helps!