# Subtract values for all columns in df1 by values in one column in df2

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I have the following dataframe `df1`:

```
 a    b    c    d
 10   15   20   25
 8    18   28   38
 20   25   30   35
```

And for simplicity, assuming I have a dataset `df2`:

```
 y
 1
 2
 3
```

I want to subtract, row-wise, values in `df2` from values in `df1`

Hence, my final dataset `df3` = `df1` - `df2` would be:

```
  a    b    c    d
  9   14   19   24
  6   16   26   36
 17   22   27   32
```

Comment: `df2` will always have one column and the same number of rows as `df1`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add/subtract dataframes with different column labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415048/add-subtract-dataframes-with-different-column-labels)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtract a Series from a DataFrame while keeping the DataFrame struct intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531990/subtract-a-series-from-a-dataframe-while-keeping-the-dataframe-struct-intact)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sub` and `axis=0` for a vectorized solution

```
df.sub(df2.values, axis=0)
```

---

```
    a   b   c   d
0   9  14  19  24
1   6  16  26  36
2  17  22  27  32
```

---

#### `Timings`

For a small number of columns:

```
%timeit (df.sub(df2.values, axis=0))
784 µs ± 15.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x - df2['y'])
2.22 ms ± 70.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: I think it's better to start use `to_numpy` instead of `values`. Besides that +1

Answer (score 4):

Maybe there is something simpler, but you can use apply

```
df1.apply(lambda x: x - df2['y'])

#   a   b   c   d
#0  9   14  19  24
#1  6   16  26  36
#2  17  22  27  32
```

`apply` will loop on all columns in df1 and substract `df2['y']`

Comment: This is partially vectorized (operation inside lambda is vectorized, but apply is basically a for loop). Will get very slow with many columns :}

Comment: You're right, I was looking for something like your solution but did not know about `sub`, +1 on your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use [`numpy broadcasting`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_broadcasting.htm) which broadcasts the 1 dimensional array of `df2` to be compatibel with the shape of `df1`:

[image]

*note: picture does not represent the correct shapes or values, but it's for the idea*
*[source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_broadcasting.htm)*

```
vals = df1.to_numpy() - df2.to_numpy()
df3 = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=df1.columns)

    a   b   c   d
0   9  14  19  24
1   6  16  26  36
2  17  22  27  32
```

---

**Timings**

```
%%timeit
vals = df1.to_numpy() - df2.to_numpy()
pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=df1.columns)
77.7 µs ± 2.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%%timeit
df1.sub(df2.values, axis=0)
646 µs ± 16.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
df1.apply(lambda x: x - df2['y'])
1.39 ms ± 12.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```